# HTML form to JSON using PHP 5.13 (multidimensional)

Tags: php, json

I've searched and searched and I've gotten close, but I'm still lacking a few things and I'm hoping I can get some additional guidance here. I'm relatively new to PHP and JSON. 
I have a need to consume a JSON file, display it in an editable HTML form, then take the changed/submitted values and overwrite the existing JSON form with the data. I've successfully consumed the JSON and displayed the form, but I'm struggling getting the form data back into the proper JSON format.
I am constrained by the fact that I am stuck using PHP 5.1.3 (yeah, I know...not by choice); JavaScript is frowned upon and the server does not have any JQuery libraries available.

Here's the HTML:

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
     <table>
        <?php read_EDT_json ( $new_edt); ?>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit"></td></tr>
     </table>
</form>
```

Here is the function:

```
function read_EDT_json($theJSON) {
if ( file_exists ( "files/" . $theJSON ) ) {
    $json = file_get_contents ( "files/" . $theJSON );

    $jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator ( new RecursiveArrayIterator ( json_decode ( $json, TRUE ) ), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );

    foreach ( $jsonIterator as $key => $value) {
    if ( is_array ( $value ) ) {
      if ( !is_numeric ( $key ) ) {
         echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><strong><input type='hidden' name='league[$key]' value='" . $key . "'>" . $key . "</input></strong></td></tr>\n";
      }
        foreach ( $value as $c => $r ) {
         if ( is_array ( $r ) ) {
          foreach ( $r as $t => $l ) {
            if ( $t === "team" ) {
             echo "<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='league[$key][team]' value='" . $l . "'>" . $l . "</input></td>";
            } else {
              echo "<td><input type='text' name='league[$key][points]' value='" . $l . "'></input></td></tr>\n";
                            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
}
```

}

And, finally, here is the action on the post (I'm not showing the write the JSON portion as I have figured out how to do that):

```
if( isset ( $_POST [ "league" ] ) ) {
   foreach ( $_POST [ "league" ] as $k => $v ) {
       $params [ $k ] = $v;
   }
echo json_encode ( $params ); 
}
```

When I retrieve the $_POST, the json_encode gives me:

```
{"EPL":{"team":"Watford","points":"12"},"MLS":{"team":"Montreal","points":"39"}}
```

I need it to look like:

```
{ "EPL": [ { "team": "Chelsea", "points": 15.0 }, { "team": "Liverpool", "points": 15.0 }, { "team": "City", "points": 13.0 }, { "team": "Waterford", "points": 12.0 }], "MLS": [ { "team": "Atlanta", "points": 57.0 }, { "team": "New York", "points": 56.0 }, { "team": "Columbus", "points": 44.0 }, { "team": "Philadelphia", "points": 40.0 }, { "team": "Montreal", "points": 39.0 }] }
```

Note: I'm only getting the final values of the inner array. I'm also not getting the "[" opener after EPL and before the first team, nor am I getting the closing "]" or opening before and after "MLS".

any advice for a relative PHP/JSON newbie would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( isset ( $_POST [ "league" ] ) ) {
    foreach ( $_POST [ "league" ] as $k => $v ) {
        if(isset($params[$k])){ // has $params[$k] already been set?
            if(is_array($params[$k])){ // $params[$k] should be an array as it has multiple values. Is it?
                array_push($params[$k],$v); // append to $params[$k]
            } else {
                $params[$k] = array($params[$k],$v); // convert $params[$k] into an array, and append $v
            }
        } else {
            $params [ $k ] = $v;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode ( $params ); 
}
```

Your code was overwring $params[$k] with whatever $v currently was, instead of treating it as an array.